# Portfolio Optimization Constraints

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, optimization

Wondering which are some standard constraints in portfolio optimization in practice?

For example, assuming we want to maximize expected returns subject to a risk constraint, typically we may have

-constraints on gross exposure
-constraints on net exposure
-constraints on individual asset gross exposure
etc.

Is there a good document/ book that has standard constraints that are used in practice?

Answer (score 2):

Constraints obviously also depend on the problem formulation (for example: weights sum to 1 will translate to active weights sum to 0 if we optimize relative positions)

Apart from the most important ones the unit investment constraints (weights sum to 1 or money invested sums to NAV), sometimes short-selling constraints,
very often you see constraints on the number of securities held or traded.

Depending on the problem, also constraints on portfolio characteristics, such as FX exposure, Non-rated or asset class exposures.

Unfortunately there is no standard literature on this.
The reason for this being: Every optimization problem is different and the constraints come from the practical application itself.

Disclosure/Addendum: One thing is considering constraints, the other one is translating them into a format the optimizer understands. More often than not, this is harder than you think.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with:

**Portfolio stability constraints**

- Long-only constraints (to avoid unrealistic short positions)
- Maximum and minimum allocation to asset classes

**Liquidity and illiquidity constraints**

- Minimum posititon in liquid instruments (money market, govies, etc.)
- Maximum hair-cut due to forced selling

**Concentration constraints**

- Asset within asset class concentration constraint (eaxh asset should not be 100% of the exposure in the particular asset class)

**Portfolio factor beta exposure**

- Minimum and maximum limits to the relative beta exposure of the portfolio aganst a given factor (e.g. market factor)

There will certaintly be more possible constraints (see e.g. the implementation [here](http://www.portfolioprobe.com/features/constraints/)).